# tx.wait with Ethers.js never resolves

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to send transactions to the polygon network using ethers.js. After submitting the transaction, i `await tx.wait()`, but it fails to resolve 50% of the time.  I saw other people were having similar issues but was due to their gas price being too low.  I currently have this code:

```
const getWallet = (): Wallet => {
  return new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, HTTP_PROVIDER);
};
const wallet = getWallet();
const gasPrice = 50000000000;
const swap1 = await wallet.sendTransaction({
      data: tx1.data,
      chainId: tx1.chainId,
      from: tx1.from,
      gasLimit: 350449, 
      gasPrice: gasPrice, 
      value: '0x' + new BigNumber(tx1.value).toString(16),
      to: tx1.to,
      nonce: nonce,
    });
```

I've always returned an object that has the tx hash, but when I go to look up that hash on polyscan it never appears. After waiting sometimes up to an hour tx.wait() still does not resolve and the transaction still doesn't appear in polyscan.

I cancel my script, bump the gasPrice up by 20% and try to run it again w/ the same nonce (hoping to replace it). At that point I'm usually told the replacement gas fee is too low.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need instance the provider first using new ethers.providers, in this example i use JsonRpcProvider.

And Alternatively to wait(),you can execute another function to wait receipt using ethers.provider.waitForTransaction(hash,confirmations,timeout).

You can do something like this:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(HTTP_PROVIDER);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
const swap1 = await wallet.sendTransaction({//});
const receipt = provider.waitForTransaction(swap1.hash, 1, 150000).then(() => {//});
```